# Почему не работает LiveEdit в webstorm?

Tags: html, css, webstorm

Почему не работает LiveEdit в webstorm?

Расширение Jetbrains IDE Support установлено

Когда нажимаю в контекстном меню Debug index.html открывается новое окно в хроме, но при изменении кода в реальном времени на странице ничего не меняется, только после перезагрузки страницы

Вот скрин настроек:
[image: Скрин настроек Debugger]

[image: Скрин настроек LiveEdit]

Comment: а какой код вы меняете - HTML, CSS, javascript? что представляет собой Ваше приложение? Расширение Jetbrains IDE Support Вам, кстати, не нужно, да Вы его и не используете, судя по настройкам

Comment: @lena только html и css, там простейшая html страница + немного css. JS вообще нет

Comment: @lena пробовал даже установить галочку на "use jetbrains ide support" - все равно код в реальном времени не обновляется

Антивирусы и фаерволы никакие не стоят

Comment: обращайтесь в техподдержку и присылайте видео проблемы

Comment: @lena Что самое забавное - если создаю новый проект, то все работает с новым проектом!